# GAE task queue enforced rate throttling performance

Tags: java, google-app-engine, task-queue

I am currently working on building a load testing platform with Google App Engine. My eventual goal is to simulate 1 million users sending data to another GAE server application every 10 minutes.

My current implementation is using task queues, where each task represents a user or handful of users. My problem is that GAE is throttling my task queues with an enforced rate well bellow my maximum/desired rate. I have tried simply throwing instances at the problem, and while this helps I still end up with an enforced rate well bellow desired.

However, I know that my application is capable of running tasks faster than the enforced rate. I have witnessed my application successfully running 250+ tasks per second for a period of time, only to have the task queue throttled to 60 or 30 tasks per second a minute later.

I am using basic scaling with a cap of 10 instances for now, and I would like to understand this problem more before increasing the instance count, as cost start running up quite quickly with a high instance count.

Does anyone have more information on why I am being throttled like this, and how to get around this throttling? The only documentation/information/answers I can find to this question simply quote the insufficient documentation, which says something like:

"The enforced rate may be decreased when your application returns a 503 HTTP response code, or if there are no instances able to execute a request for an extended period of time."

I am happy to clarify any questions, thank you in advance for your help I have been wrestling with this problem for about a month.

Comment: Are you trying to send through all of the 10 million users data through at exactly the same time very ten minutes, or have you distributed it evenly over your 10 minute intervals?

Comment: Distributed evenly, I tried filling the queue more slowly by waiting 6ms after enqueuing each task but this seemed to have no effect. @DaffyPunk

Comment: Perhaps a measure to prevent stack overflows on your task queues, or DoS prevention measure?

Comment: I don't think it would be a stack overflow thing because google makes no mention of a maximum queue size, and they don't limit the rate at which I can add tasks to the queue. The queue is just a list of URLs to servlets, and I never have more than 10,000 in the queue right now. I have definitely considered DoS, but Im really not dealing with that much volume right now (I'm focusing on just simulating 10,000 users for now). Also, I know you can do load testing with google compute engine and JMeter, so I dont understand why they would throttle GAE when you could just use GCE. @DaffyPunk